# R system.time() as a number

Tags: r, data-structures, casting, decimal, benchmarking

I'm using system.time() function to measure the time elapsed of my code, but I need it to be a number in order to plot it into a graph. Unfortunately the structure of system.time() output is more complex than a number, a thing like this:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  0.101   0.000   0.100
```

I would like to convert this structure into just a number, user elapsed time would be great => 0.101

I have tried as.double(tt$elapsed[[1]]) but is not a number yet. Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of blind hope, you should investigate the structure of an object using `str`.

Comment: Thanks, @Roland str() is a great tool I didn't know about. In this case its output is `Class 'proc_time'  Named num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "user.self" "sys.self" "elapsed" "user.child" ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tt` object is  `proc_time` class, and is actually a `Named` numeric.  So, basically a named `vector`.

```
unname(tt[3])
```

Or as  @Matthew Plourde mentioned

```
tt[['elapsed']]
```

can be also used.

Comment: another option is `tt[['elapsed']]`